# Django Registration Redux: how to change the unique identifier from username to email and use email as login

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using `django-registration-redux` in my project for user registration. It uses default `User` model which use `username` as the unique identifier.

Now we want to discard `username` and use `email` as the unique identifier.

And also we want to use `email` instead of `username` to login.

How to achieve this?

And is it possible to do it without changing the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings?

Because from the official doc it says

> If you intend to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you should set it before creating any migrations or running `manage.py` migrate for the first time.

Answer (score 7):

You can override registration form like this

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
class MyRegForm(RegistrationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        self.cleaned_data['username'] = email
        return email
```

And then add this to settings file (read this [link](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/default-backend.html) for details)

```
REGISTRATION_FORM = 'app.forms.MyRegForm'
```

This will set the email to username field as well and then everything will work as email is now the username.

The only problem is that username field has a max lenght of 30 in DB. So emails longer than 30 chars will raise DB exception. To solve that override the user model (read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for details).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is in fact a hack way, but actually it works. Simply it will set username to be the the same as given email address. And all the rest works as before, no need to customize User model.

Comment: I've got an error in relation to "Required=False" and had to correct to "require=False". The solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to made your own [custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

This is the example

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Then, you need to set the User Model in your Django settings. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#auth-user-model

Comment: the official doc says"If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time", so will this break the migration

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use AbstractBaseUser. Docs are here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/

Good luck!