# Right way to implement email whitelist solution for Django-registration-redux?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-registration

I have working solution however I affraid my solution isn't much pythonic. So I hope somebody will suggest a better way.

With Django ver 1.8.2 I am using django-registration-redux ver 1.2. I have my own form therefore I have setting `REGISTRATION_FORM = 'login_app.forms.MyRegForm'`.

Additionally I need a feature so that only whitelisted emails are allowed to register. According to `registration/backends/default/urls.py` register view is handled by class `RegistrationView` in `registration/backends/default/views.py`:

```
...
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
...
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(),
        name='registration_register'),
...
```

`RegistrationView` class can be viewed on [Github](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/default/views.py). Because this class with it's functions provides required functionality I have subclassed it and copied all it's content only adding few lines of my code. In my `login_app.views.py`:

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
# and many other imports to satisfy actions inside MyRegView

class MyRegView(RegistrationView):
    # some copied code
    def register(self, request, form):
        # some copied code
        WHITELISTED_EMAILS = getattr(settings, 'WHITELISTED_EMAILS')
        email_to_check = form.cleaned_data['email']
        if email_to_check in WHITELISTED_EMAILS:
            # registration performed
            # by using copied code
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        # remaining copied code
```

Finally I have overwritten url so that the right view is used:

```
...
from login_app.views import MyRegView

urlpatterns = [
     ...
     url(r'^accounts/register/', MyRegView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
     ... 
    ]
```

This solution works fine, but I am copying too much code. What is more elegant solution for whitelist implementation?

Comment: There is normally no need to copy entire methods unchanged from superclass to subclass.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: Most likely because of lacking OOP concepts. I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to add a `clean_email` method to your registration form, and do the whitelisting there.

```
class MyRegForm(ParentForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        # If the parent class already cleans the email, you might want to do
        # email = super(MyRegForm, self).clean_email()
        # Then check email here, and raise forms.ValidationError() 
        # if the email is not in the whitelist
        return email
```

Comment: I will check it out and will come back most likely tomorrow.

Comment: Although I don't get why I might use option `email = super(MyRegForm, self).clean_email()`, the suggested solution works fine and simple to implement. Thanks.

Comment: If `ParentForm` already had a `clean_email` method, then your `clean_method` method would replace it. Calling `super()` would call the method of the parent class. This avoids having to copy paste code from the parent class to the child class. Overriding a method and calling `super()` is a pretty standard technique. On second thoughts, I think it's unlikely that your parent class has a `clean_email` method, but you didn't include it in your question, so I mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: As provided in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358213/2647009) I am subclassing `RegistrationForm` from [registration.forms](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/forms.py). While looking into `RegistrationForm` class I don't find `clean_email` method. So that means code is ok.

Comment: Yes, if `RegistrationForm` (or its parent classes) do not have a `clean_email` method, then you don't have to call `super()`.