# Populate first_name and last_name from full_name

Tags: django, django-registration

When a user registers in my app, he must enter a `full_name`. The [`UserModel`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#user) has no full_name field, but `first_name` and `last_name`, so I have a naive function which is good enough for my use case:

```
def split_full_name(full_name):
    if not full_name:
        first_name, last_name = None, None
    else:
        parts = full_name.split(' ')
        if len(parts) == 1:
            first_name = parts[0]
            last_name = None
        elif len(parts) == 2:
            first_name = parts[0]
            last_name = parts[1]
        else:
            first_name = parts[0]
            last_name = ' '.join(parts[1:])
    return first_name, last_name
```

I am overriding the registration form as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358213/647991):

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

    full_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean_full_name(self):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data['full_name']
        first_name, last_name = split_full_name(full_name)
        self.cleaned_data['first_name'] = first_name
        self.cleaned_data['last_name'] = last_name
        return full_name
```

But the `first_name` and `last_name` from the `cleaned_data` are not saved to the model. What should I do to achieve that?

I have seen the [use of hidden fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358213/647991) for that, but I would like something a bit less hacky. Can I manually populate some fields of the user instance during form validation / processing?

### EDIT

Just to avoid confussion: I **do not want to add** a `full_name` field to the `UserModel`. I am just using the stock `UserModel`, but I want to simplify the form by allowing the user to enter `full_name` directly and then programatically generating `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: you can customize the user model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @ofnowhereland: I don't need to customize the user model. It has everything I need.

Comment: @Sayse: maybe I have not been clear enough. The `full_name` is just a form field, not a user model field. The fields in the user model are indeed `first_name` and `last_name` (as defined in the stock UserModel), and *not* `full_name`, so there is no duplication. I just don't want to force the user to fill in two separate fields in the form.

Comment: Ah ok so this is purely an almost cosmetic front end thing (or usability anyway). I would have expected the form code you've provided to work....Do you get any errors with this (form invalid?)? (I've removed my previous comments to remove noise from your question)

Comment: @Sayse: yes, I guess you can call it a usability thing. And no errors at all, but the model fields `first_name` and `last_name` are not populated.

Comment: Possibly an issue in your actual form saving then... the only other thing I'd suggest is set breakpoints in the form `clean_first_name` / `last_name` methods and see what order they are populated in, its possible that your values are being overridden before you get anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the first name and last name on the form's instance, instead of adding them to `cleaned_data`.

```
def clean_full_name(self):
    full_name = self.cleaned_data['full_name']
    first_name, last_name = split_full_name(full_name)
    self.instance.first_name = first_name
    self.instance.last_name = last_name
    return full_name
```

If that doesn't work, I would try overriding the form's `save()` method and set the values there.

As an aside, you might have issues assigning `None` to `first_name` and `last_name`. I would use the empty string `''` instead.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I do not understand what are the roles of `cleaned_data` vs `instance` values. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Every form has a clean methods that return `cleaned_data`. `ModelForm`s also have an `instance`, which is the (existing or new) object that is being edited. When the form is validated, the values from `cleaned_data` are used to update the `instance`. In your case, because the `RegistrationForm` does not have `first_name` and `last_name` fields, adding them to `cleaned_data` will not work, so we modify the instance directly. You might find the docs for [validation on a model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) useful.